# Work with Radxa GPIO in Android Shell

Tags: android, gpio

I want to control GPIOs in my Radxa Lite, currently I am using below codes to set value of my desired GPIO but it doesn't work:

```
adb shell
echo 192 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio192/direction

echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio192/value
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio192/value
```

It doesn't work, I tried with gpio 162 and 198, same results.
I am following the tutorial in **[this](http://radxa.com/Rock/GPIO#Shell)** page.
Even the same codes (making the green LED blink, with gpio 172) does not work!

however I can control LEDs using the instruction in **[this](http://radxa.com/Rock/LED)** page.

*Note:* when I enter "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio192/value" and then 
"cat value", it seems there is no changes made to "value" file, still returns "0", I tried changing the file access to 777 (chmod 777 value) but it didn't make any difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your adb shell running as root?  What are the permissions of the device nodes?  Is gpio192 actually valid?  After you have done the export, what does `ls -l /sys/class/gpio192` show?

Comment: Yes it's running as root, I checked the permissions, first the permissions for export file was --w---- or something like this, after a "chmod 777 export" it becomes "-rwxrwxrwx root     root         4096 2011-01-01 12:14 export", which seems ok. 
I've tried other gpios but none of them worked (even the gpio172 that is responsible for green led), it returns "/system/bin/sh: can't create /sys/class/gpio/gpio172/value: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

I've put my excample to [my Website](http://baggerautomatik.selfhost.eu) from the download you can get the code works in my system radxaRockPro and is controlled over Android
I'hpe it can help you to get startet (I'm german)

Comment: Thanks for your attention dude, but your website seems to be broken, it does not open.